# Given a smooth function $f$ for which $\lim_\limits{x\to\pm \infty}f^{(n)}(x)=0.$ Do the derivatives of $f(1/x)$ also tend to $0$ as $x\to0$?

Tags: limits, functions

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^\infty$ and has the property that, for all $n \ge 0,$ the $n$th derivative $f^{(n)}(x)\to0$ as $x \to \pm\infty$.  If we now define $g(x)=f(1/x)$ for nonzero $x$ and $g(0)=0,$ does it follow that for all $n \ge 0$ we have $g^{(n)}(0)=0$?

This came up for me when trying to verify the function $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$  for nonzero $x$ with $f(0)=0$ had the property that it is not equal to its power series, since the latter is the zero function. Taking the derivative of this particular $f$ using the chain and product rules became quickly involved, and then I thought that *if* my question above had answer "yes" it would make this (and other) example(s) easier to verify.

Comment: For the function $e^{-1/x^2}$ it's straight forward to do an induction with an arbitrary rational as the coefficient instead of trying to figure out the general term.

Comment: No. For a counterexample consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \quad$ so $\quad g(x)=x$.

Comment: @gandalf61 That's not $C^\infty(\Bbb R)$. It's easily remedied, but still.

Comment: @Arthur Take $x/(x^2+1)$ to fix the issue at $0$.

Comment: @gandalf61 I could be mistaking, but I fail to see how that's a counter example. Eventhough $f\notin C^\infty(\mathbb R)$, we nevertheless have that $\lim_\limits{x\to\pm\infty}f^{(n)}(x)=0$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to0} g^{(n)}(x)=0$....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
g(x) =& f(h(x))\\
g'(x) =& f'(h(x))h'(x) = -f(1/x)/x^2\\
\lim_{x\to 0} g'(x) =& -\lim_{x\to 0} f(1/x)/x^2  = -\lim_{y\to \infty} f(y)\, y^2 =0
\end{eqnarray}

In the case for n = 1 this only happens when $f(y)$ drops quicker than $y^2$. So there should be an infinite amount of other function out there which do not behave as you want.

Comment: I see you point. It works in particular for the example $x/(1+x^2)$ given in a comment of Arthur. I'll likely accept.. +1 for now.